# how to enable the usage of EditText inside a PopupWindow ?

Tags: android, popupwindow, textedit

I have an EditText inside a PopupWindow.
The problem is that when i touch the EditText the SoftKeyboard is not visible. does any one have an idea how  do i get the SoftKeyboard the show up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the popup window focuseable with popupWindow.setFocusable(true). The softkeyboard can be added in on your manifest file.